# Determine the distribution used to generate a dataset

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayes-theorem

I know that a dataset was generated $2/5$ of the times using a standard Gaussian and $3/5$ (which we call $C_1$) of the times using a student #t# with parameter $\nu = 1$ (we call this $C2$). I want to use Bayes' Theorem to compute the probability that the dataset was generated by this or that distribution. In order to do this, I would take the first element of my data set (though order doesn't matter), compute

$$ P(D=C_i|x)= \frac{P(x|D=C_i)P(D=C_i)}{P(x|D=C_1)P(D=C_1)+P(x|D=C_2)P(D=C_2)}
$$

and then proceed in the same way on the next element, substituting to the $P(D=C_i)$ the posterior I just found, $P(D=C_i|x)$.  Is this approach correct?

Comment: I'm a little confused at the nature of this probability experiment. Is each point in the dataset randomly selected from either $C_1$ or $C_2$, or is the *entire dataset* consisting of repeated observations of a single one of these distributions?

Comment: Entire dataset generated using one of the two distros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to find the probability that a particular observation came from the standard normal distribution rather than the $t$ distribution.

Let's call the density of the normal distribution $\phi(x)$, and the density of the $t$ distribution $f_t(x)$.  We can use these as likelihoods in Bayes theorem and say $$\mathbb P(\text{Normal} \mid x) = \dfrac{\frac25 \phi(x)}{\frac25 \phi(x) +\frac35 f_t(x)}$$

I think this is what you have done, except that where you wrote  $P(x\mid D=C_i)$ you have a minor typo in the subscript, and more importantly you should be using a density and (as Matthew Pilling commented) not a probability

If you are now saying the whole dataset was generated by just one of the distributions (with the $\frac25:\frac35$ prior as to which one) then you want $$\mathbb P(\text{Normal} \mid \mathbf x) = \dfrac{\frac25 \prod\limits_i  \phi(x_i)}{\frac25  \prod\limits_i \phi(x_i) +\frac35  \prod\limits_i  f_t(x_i)}.$$  You could do this iteratively but you get the same answer more quickly doing it all at once

Comment: Of course, where I write $P(x|...)$ I mean a density. So this procedure is correct and I can iterate it for each element of the dataset? All the points are generated according to one of the two distributions, and I want to find out which i.e. assign probabilities to both.

Comment: You are not going to find out which, but you can assign conditional probabilities based on your $\frac25:\frac35$ spit and the actual values of $x$

Comment: Yes, and my doubt is: if I do this with that split the first time but then proceed iteratively by substituting that split with the new $P(D=C_i|x)$ I get a sort of better approximation of what distribution generated the whole dataset, right?

Comment: If you are now saying the whole dataset was generated by just one of the distributions (with the $\frac25:\frac35$ prior as to which one) then you want $$\mathbb P(\text{Normal} \mid \mathbf x) = \dfrac{\frac25 \prod \phi(x_i)}{\frac25  \prod \phi(x_i) +\frac35  \prod f_t(x_i)}.$$  You could do this iteratively but you get the same answer more quickly doing it all at once

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I don't see why this formula with the whole dataset would hold. Can you please explain?

Comment: It is just updating the prior with the likelihood to get the posterior distribution.  Suppose you just had two observations $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Then after the first you would get $\dfrac{\frac25 \phi(x_1)}{\frac25 \phi(x_1) +\frac35 f_t(x_1)}$  and then after the second $\dfrac{\frac{\frac25 \phi(x_1)}{\frac25 \phi(x_1) +\frac35 f_t(x_1)} \phi(x_2)}{\frac{\frac25 \phi(x_1)}{\frac25 \phi(x_1) +\frac35 f_t(x_1)} \phi(x_2) +\frac{\frac35 f_t(x_1)}{\frac25 \phi(x_1) +\frac35 f_t(x_1)} f_t(x_2)}$ $=\dfrac{\frac25 \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2)}{\frac25 \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2) +\frac35 f_t(x_1) f_t(x_2)}$